# Python Grouping For Column Display

Tags: python, iteration

I have a set of data

```
data = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
```

Usually in python I'll group these for display across row of `n` columns:

```
cols = 4
grouped = izip_longest(*(iter(data),)*cols)
```

That gives me a great row display:

```
grouped = ( (1,2,3,4), (5,6,7,8), (9,10,None,None) )
```

which , on a templated website, would look like

```
1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8
9  10
```

Now i'm trying to wrap my head around a different display - down the column & across `n` rows

```
1  4  7  10
2  5  8  
3  6  9
```

because this is for web templating, I need to generate a set of this data :

```
grouped = ( (1,4,7,10), (2,5,8,None), (3,6,9,None) )
```

Honestly, I'm at a complete loss on how to best approach this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is a call to [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
In [10]: rows = 3

In [11]: zip(*itertools.izip_longest(*(iter(data),)*rows))
Out[11]: [(1, 4, 7, 10), (2, 5, 8, None), (3, 6, 9, None)]
```

Basically, it uses exactly the same algorithm as yours, and then [transposes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) the result.

Comment: `transpose` - that's the word I was looking for!  thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

You need to adjust the length, then re-zip it:

```
>>> zip(*izip_longest(*[iter(data)]*3))
[(1, 4, 7, 10), (2, 5, 8, None), (3, 6, 9, None)]
```